# Why can we not write the reals as a countable union of sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I understand that the reals are not countable, what goes wrong with this? $$\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n,n) $$

Comment: What you have their is a countable union of a countable family of subsets of ${\mathbb{R}}$. These subsets themselves are not countable

Comment: You are supposing $(-n,n)$ is a interval on the reals, which is a little circular.  If they were intervals on the rationals, you would have $\mathbb Q = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n,n)$ which has a different cardinaity

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is the trivial union of a single set: $\Bbb R$. Every set is. The interesting property is whether a set can be written as a countable union of *countable* sets, and that's where $\Bbb R$ fails.

Comment: We can even take the family to be a singleton, i.e. a family having only one set as its element: $\mathbb R = \bigcup\{\mathbb R\}$. This is a countable (singleton!) family of uncountable sets. Vice versa, we can take the family being a family of singleton sets: $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R} \{x\}$. This is an uncountable family of countable (singleton!) sets. What we can't take is a countable family of countable sets and still have its union to be $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write the reals like that but since every interval with more than 1 element is uncountable, you wrote $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of uncountable sets, which is still uncountable.